# On monomial matrices (Generalized Permutation Matrices )

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-verification, semidirect-product

A matrix $a\in GL_{n}(F)$ is said to be *monomial* if each row and column has exactly one non-zero entry. Let $N$ denote **the set of all monomial matrices.**

I have already proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943187/on-monomial-matrix-generalized-permutation-matrix) that the  following are equivalent

- $A\in N$
- there exist a non singular $D$ (diagonal matrix ) and a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A=DP$
- there exist a non singular $D$ (diagonal matrix ) and a permutation matrix $P$ such that $A=PD$

My aim is to show the following

1) **$N$ is a subgroup of $G=GL_{n}(F)$.**

2) **$T=B\cap N$ is the subgroup of $G$ consisting of all diagonal matrices.**

3) **$N$ is a semi direct product of $T$ and $W$, here $W$ is group of all permutation matrices.**

4) **$N=N_{G}(T)$, normalizer of $T$ in $G$.**

5) **$N_{G}(T)/T$ is generated by finite set $S$ of involutions (elements of degree 2) and $|S|=n-1$.**

Using the above mentioned lemma, I have proved 1, 2 and 4 is already solved  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108593/how-to-prove-that-the-normalizer-of-diagonal-matrices-in-gl-n-is-the-subgroup).

I have made an attempt to solve question 3. Please correct me if my reasoning for question 3 is wrong.

Now by the lemma, we conclude $N=WT$ also $W\cap T$ is trivial, so now only thing left to show is that $T$ is normal in $N$, but it is obvious from question 4 (since $N_{G}(T)=N$, restricting it to $N$, $N_{G}(T)|_{N}=N$ hence $T$ is normal subgroup). So $N$ is indeed a semidirect product of $T$ and $W$.

But I am not able to solve question $5$, Kindly help.

Comment: It should be generated by the permutation matrices which correspond to transpositions. You can use $(12), \ldots (n-1 n)$ to generate all permutations

Comment: @NickR what about question 3 , I have written solution for question 3, is it correct ?

Comment: Seems correct to me!